# Bootstrap Dropdown does not work for me

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Chrome on OS X, and when I do a plain vanilla Bootstrap test it doesn't work.

I use the regular v2.3.2 files [downloaded from here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html), and I re-created a vanilla test.

This is how my `index.html` looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script>
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
</script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Hello</h2>

    <p>There should be a dropdown right below this paragraph.</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

When I do this, this is what I see:

[image: Bootstrap Dropdown Not Working]

Yet in the source, I see this outputted:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Hello</h2>

    <p>There should be a dropdown right below this paragraph.</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: After the source you linked, don't you forget the '<a class="dropdown-toggle"...' just before the 'ul ' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to including the dropdown trigger before the unordered list (`the <a>`) you've also forgotten to wrap your menu with an element that has the `.dropdown` class, e.g.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/73/

Answer (score 1):

With adding a 'a' tag before the ul, like write in http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#dropdowns

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope...doesn't work for me. Btw...my code is copied str8 from the bootstrap docs - http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#dropdowns

Comment: When I do what you suggest, it just adds a link called `Dropdown trigger`....but no dropdown works.

Comment: Do you call the js ? $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()

Comment: Just added it to the `index.html` but no dice. Updating the code to reflect the changes I made.